# dummynet corruption, reordering of package

Tags: ipfw, dummynet

I am new to dummynet/ipfw and I would like to know if I can do a couple of things using this tool.

1 - I need to make an exception in the pipe of a particular IP but that for all the others if the filters are applied. How could I do this?

2- I need to generate corruption, reordering and loss of package. So far I've only seen the option of packet loss and bandwidth limitation. Can you also apply corruption, packet reordering?

Thank you!
Regards!